# Is there a way to calculate the number of days between dates, for various sites, and where specific days have to be discounted?

Tags: r, datetime

I am looking to calculate the number of days that traps were working for various sites within a study area.

I have a data set that contains multiple survey sites, with each checked on multiple dates. I am seeking a way to calculate the number of days between each check for each site. There is a slight catch, as for some sites and dates, the trap was broken. For these, I will need all the days until the closest previous date when the trap was working to be classed as "non-working days", and as such not counted.

here is a subset of the data -

```
structure(list(Date.of.Survey = c("12/04/2022", "16/04/2022", 
"12/04/2022", "13/04/2022", "14/04/2022", "15/04/2022", "18/04/2022", 
"19/04/2022", "20/04/2022", "22/04/2022", "26/04/2022", "27/04/2022", 
"28/04/2022", "29/04/2022", "01/05/2022", "03/05/2022", "04/05/2022", 
"05/05/2022", "06/05/2022", "12/05/2022", "10/05/2022", "11/05/2022", 
"12/05/2022", "13/05/2022", "19/05/2022", "17/05/2022", "18/05/2022", 
"19/05/2022", "20/05/2022", "27/05/2022", "24/05/2022", "25/05/2022", 
"26/05/2022", "27/05/2022", "04/06/2022", "31/05/2022", "01/06/2022", 
"02/06/2022", "03/06/2022", "07/06/2022", "08/06/2022", "09/06/2022", 
"10/06/2022", "18/06/2022", "14/06/2022", "15/06/2022", "16/06/2022", 
"17/06/2022", "21/06/2022", "22/06/2022", "23/06/2022", "24/06/2022", 
"28/06/2022", "29/06/2022", "30/06/2022", "01/07/2022", "05/07/2022", 
"06/07/2022", "07/07/2022", "08/07/2022"), Location = c("Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", 
"Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir", 
"Medway - Allington Weir", "Medway - Allington Weir"), Was.the.trap.working.when.you.checked.it. = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), Number.of.eels = c(0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 16L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Ideally I would like to have a table that shows total number of days that each sites trap was functioning, with a column showing the total number of fish caught at each trap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your specific question? ... it is unclear, but it seems that you are wanting for someone to write code for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen these traps being laid - it's very interesting and the workers very kindly explained what they were doing.

Anyway, regarding the question. You can do something along the lines of:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat |>
    mutate(survey_date = as.Date(
        Date.of.Survey,
        format = "%d/%m/%Y"
    )) |>
    arrange(Location, survey_date) |>
    group_by(Location) |>
    mutate(
        lag_date = lag(survey_date), 
        num_days = as.integer(survey_date - lag_date)
    )  |>
    filter(
        Was.the.trap.working.when.you.checked.it. == "Yes"
    )  |>
    summarise(
        total_days_trap_working = sum(num_days, na.rm = TRUE), 
        total_eels = sum(Number.of.eels)
    )

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Location                    total_days_trap_working total_eels
#   <chr>                                         <int>      <int>
# 1 Medway - Allington Weir                          82         78
# 2 Wandle - Merton Abbey Mills                      67          7
```

Comment: Hi Sam, I have been going through the data, and taking a look at it by month. I realised that the code was calculating the number of days working between survey dates. But there are some cases where the data was entered when only eels were caught, for example twice in one month, but the trap was working throughout the whole month. So for example there were captures on the 4th and 18th June, so the code recognises it as 14 working days, when it should be the whole month working. Is there a way you could help again. Many Thanks, Sam

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to update the question with a minimal sample dataset where this code gets the wrong result, and I will try to take a look at it. Or if it is the wrong result with the data already posted can you provide a bit more info about what is happening? I don't quite understand what isn't working.